# I've an issue with my Javascript code the console keep saying > Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I want to display a video(that is hidden from the user) when I hit the button watch-video in the jumbotron I've with a hero image. I want to hide that section and them show the video that is embed from Youtube. This my entire JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Back to top button function 
    $(".button-back-to-top").click(function(){
    $("body,html").animate({
        scrollTop:"0px"
    }, 680);
  });
     $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400 ) {
        $(".button-back-to-top").slideDown(800);
    } else {
        $(".button-back-to-top").slideUp(800);
    }
  });

  //Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
   $("body").scrollspy({target: ".navbar"})

  // jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
 $(function() {$('body').on('click', 'a.scrollable', function(event) {
   var $anchor = $(this);
 $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: 
 $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top},1500,'easeInOutExpo');
     event.preventDefault();
   });
 });
 /*THIS ACTIVATE THE BTN WATCH VIDEO TO HIDE THE BACKGROUND AND SHOW THE 
   VIDEO OF YOUTUBE*/
  $('#watch-video').click(function(){
    $('#home').fadeOut(800ms).delay(1s);
    $('#video').fadeIn(800ms);
    });
   });
```

Any clue?

Comment: Tip for the future; if you double click the error in the console it will take you to the line of code causing the problem. In this case it's the `VIDEO OF YOUTUBE` comment which you've placed a return in

Comment: thats a comment... I know how to read the console

Comment: Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: Are you sure? As it's pretty clear to anyone who can read the console that you have several other issues, such as using values of `800ms` and `1s` which are not valid integers, nor are they strings.

Comment: Oops! rockie mistake jeje ... Thanks! that was the problem

Answer (score 2):

`VIDEO OF YOUTUBE` needs to be commented out.

Also, in `fadeOut`/`fadeId` at the end, change `800ms` and `1s` to `800` and `1000` respectively.